# How do you implement caching in Linq to SQL?

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-sql, iis, caching

We've just started using LINQ to SQL at work for our DAL & we haven't really come up with a standard for out caching model.  Previously we had being using a base 'DAL' class that implemented a cache manager property that all our DAL classes inherited from, but now we don't have that.  I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a 'standard' approach to caching LINQ to SQL results?

We're working in a web environment (IIS) if that makes a difference. I know this may well end up being a [subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective) question, but I still think the info would be valuable.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm not talking about caching an individual result, I'm after more of an architecture solution, as in how do you set up caching so that all your link methods use the same caching architecture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick answer: Use the Repository pattern (see Domain Driven Design by Evans) to fetch your entities. Each repository will cache the things it will hold, ideally by letting each instance of the repository access a singleton cache (each thread/request will instantiate a new repository but there can be only one cache).

The above answer works on one machine only. To be able to use this on many machines, use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) as your caching solution. Good luck!

Comment: Note that this approach doesn't really have much to do with LINQ  or LINQ to SQL. Repository-based APIs aren't composable with further LINQ queries.

Comment: You should turn off Object Tracking when using the Repository pattern. Otherwise this will break at the discretion of the Repository:

`repository.Get(1).ReferencedTable.Id`

...since ".ReferencedTable" will be hard for the cached list to look up without a context.

Answer (score 39):

My [LINQ query result cache](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/caching-the-results-of-linq-queries/) is probably just what you're looking for.

```
var q = from c in context.Customers
        where c.City == "London"
        select new { c.Name, c.Phone };

var result = q.Take(10).FromCache();
```

Pete.

Comment: That is a brilliant piece of code, something like this needs building into the framework.

Comment: It's 2017 and I was looking for a similar solution and found this https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus project

Answer (score 4):

It's right under your nose:

```
List<TableItem> myResult = (from t in db.Table select t).ToList();
```

Now, just cache myResult as you would have cached your old DAL's returned data.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post](http://cticoder.wordpress.com/2009/11/25/linq2sql-caching-with-sqldependency/), which offers an extension method as a means of caching the LINQ objects.

I've been banging my head against the wall for weaks now trying to figure out a good caching solution for Linq2SQL, an must admit that I'm really struggling to find a one-size fits all...

The repository pattern tends to limit the usefullness of Linq, since (without reimplementing IQueryable) caching must bge performed outside of Linq statement.

Moreover, deferred loading and object tracking are both big no-nos if you're going to cache your objects, which makes performing updates somewhat trickier.

Anyone who's managed to solve this problem in the wild within a highly concurrent web project, please chime in and save the world! :)

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is perhaps a bit late answer... Non the less, you can give a try to the [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) project. It hooks a SqlDepdency on an arbitrary LINQ query, if possible, and provides active cache invalidation via the server side Query Notifications. The queries must be valid queries for notifications, see [Creating a Query for Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx). Most Linq-to-sql queries conform to these restrictions, as long as the tables are specified using two-part names (`dbo.Table`, not only `Table`).

Comment: I have setup a basic L2S model with a single table (Request) and I am trying to use LinqToCache for a basic query `from r in ctx.Requests select r`. However, it keeps failing with the exception `When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.` Any ideas?

Comment: @James: Call `SqlDependency.Start ()`?

Comment: My bad, I stupidly thought `AsCached` was triggering `SqlDependency.Start()` internally...then realised that would make no sense! That's it working now, thanks. Nice work btw, any hope for this working with E2F in the future?

Comment: @James: I haven't check what EF4 is up to, but the chances of working anytime soon are slim...

Comment: Shame, however, L2S is just as good for what I need it for. Another quick question - in the CachedQueryOptions what is the `UtcQueryTime` used for? I am trying to implement a select query which will only return records which are newer since the last update. I was wondering if this was used in anyway for that?

Answer (score 0):

See the 'GetReferenceData' method in the 'ReferenceData' class in [this article](http://blog.huagati.com/res/index.php/2008/06/23/application-architecture-part-2-data-access-layer-dynamic-linq/):
http://blog.huagati.com/res/index.php/2008/06/23/application-architecture-part-2-data-access-layer-dynamic-linq/

It uses the asp.net page cache for caching data retrieved using L2S.